# Algorithm optimization on date calculation

Tags: javascript, optimization, algorithm, datetime

I need to calculate the calendar week of a given date. Constraints:

- It should be properly calculated based on ISO 8601 if week starts on
  Monday
- It should calculate based on US standards if the week starts on
  Sunday
- It should be compact and fast, as the routine gets called very often
- It should work even if the year start is not January (Fiscal Year starts on October for instance)

That's what I have currently:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() { // ISO Week

    this.firstDay = 4;  // ISO 8601: Week with the first thursday which contains the 4th of January
    this.thursday = 4;  // 0 = Sunday OR Monday (if WeekStart = "M")

    if ( this.weekStart != 'M' )
    {
        this.firstDay = 1;  // switch to US norm: Week with the 1st of January
        this.thursday = 0;
    }

    // finding the date of the "thursday" in this week
    var donnerstag = function(datum, that) { 
        var Do = new Date(datum.getFullYear(), datum.getMonth(), 
                   datum.getDate() - datum.getDay() + that.thursday, 0, 0, 0);
        return Do;
    };

    // copy date, hourly times set to 0
    var Datum = new Date(this.getFullYear(),this.getMonth(),this.getDate(), 0, 0, 0); 

    var DoDat = donnerstag(Datum, this);        // the date of the first week
    var kwjahr = DoDat.getFullYear();           // the year of that date

    // diff from there to this date
    var DoKW1 = donnerstag(new Date(kwjahr, this.FYStart, this.firstDay), this); 
    //console.log(DoDat + " - " + DoKW1);

    // calculate the week
    var kw = Math.floor(1.5+(DoDat.getTime()-DoKW1.getTime())/86400000/7) 

    // adjust overflow
    if ( kw < 1 )
        kw = 52 + kw;

    return kw;
};
```

Is there any more compact algorithm or can this be optimized in terms of performance?

Comment: Hmm, the mix of German variable names and English comments is amusing. For better understanding: `kw` stands for the *week of year*, `donnerstag` and `Do` are *Thursday*.

Comment: @amon: yepp, right. Reason for the mix: someone started (in German) and I took over. I am generally used to "code" in English entirely

Comment: If your project does many date manipulations involving javascript, it might be useful to get a 3rd party library like moment.js. Of course, for a single function this would be abit much, but if you have many of these functions, it could be worth investing.

Comment: @Nate: thanks for the tip. Way overloaded currently but good to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, Moment.js is somewhat too heavy for this simple task. Did some profiling not too long ago and the library does too much movement for this task. Maybe it's for robustness/scalability/compatibility purposes, but nevertheless, still heavy.

Straight to the point, check out [this blog post](http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/33796/14863/calculate-iso-8601-week-and-year-in-javascript.html) which demonstrates his method of getting the ISO week. It appends an additional `getWeek` method to the native `Date` object. I have used this in one of my projects as substitute for Moment.js's ISO week function.

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function () {  
    // Create a copy of this date object  
    var target  = new Date(this.valueOf());  

    // ISO week date weeks start on monday so correct the day number  
    var dayNr   = (this.getDay() + 6) % 7;  

    // ISO 8601 states that week 1 is the week with the first thursday of that year.  
    // Set the target date to the thursday in the target week  
    target.setDate(target.getDate() - dayNr + 3);  

    // Store the millisecond value of the target date  
    var firstThursday = target.valueOf();  

    // Set the target to the first thursday of the year  
    // First set the target to january first  
    target.setMonth(0, 1);  
    // Not a thursday? Correct the date to the next thursday  
    if (target.getDay() != 4) target.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4 - target.getDay()) + 7) % 7);  

    // The weeknumber is the number of weeks between the   
    // first thursday of the year and the thursday in the target week  
    return 1 + Math.ceil((firstThursday - target) / 604800000); // 604800000 = 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000  
}
```

As for your code:

- I suggest putting it in plain English as much as you can. Readability will be an issue for reviewers who prefer verbose, purposeful naming.
- Compared to the proposed code I have put up, your version creates way more `Date` objects (3 at my count). This could be a significant bottleneck if you are calling this function over a set of tabulated data. This is going to eat memory and CPU time.
- "Cloning" a `Date` is as simple as `var clone  = new Date(original.valueOf());`. No need to individually call months, dates, etc. to setup the clone.

Comment: Thanks for the code and reco's. Your solution does not take into account different start of Fiscal Year and can not switch to US standard. Anyway +1

Comment: Cloning the date is fine, BUT: in order to set the clock to midnight  you need an additional call of setHours, ...Minutes, ...Seconds. Leaving the date at the current clock may result in rounding errors.